# cPanel 'No such user here'. Local account issue?

Tags: email, phpmailer, cpanel, whm

I have a website hosted outside the organization. The mail server to recieve the message is inside the organization. The website submits a simple form to email using PHP mail function. Works on every domain tested for the recipient except for ones internal to the domain.

So website is www.domain.com. Mail server is mail.domain.com. Hosted at separate sites. When www.domain.com wants to send a message to user@domain.com it should lookup the mx record and notice that mail.domain.com is at another location and forward the message.

If I configure it to send to user@otherdomain.com, the message is successfully sent and received. But sending to the same domain responds with 550 error 'No such user here'. So I'm wondering if the webserver thinks it is supposed to be the recipient of the mail, and thus responds with 'No user here' because, frankly there is no user configured there.

So does anyone know what cpanel/whm settings need to be added/adjusted to allow this server to know that it is not responsible for mail exchanging for this domain. I do have the mx record setup properly, but don't know if it also requires an A record for the address. Any help much appreciated.

I did notice others having the same issues, but no solutions were actually proposed, so I figured I would make my own question, and see if it get's a good answer for others too that may experience the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your routing settings are incorrect. Navigate to `cPanel` >> `MX Entry` and verify that the routing setting is `Remote Mail Exchanger`

As the mails are to be delivered externally, setting this as `Local Mail Exchanger` will make cPanel think the mails are setup locally and cPanel will try to deliver mails locally. As there are no local mail accounts configured with that name, it bounces with the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding sending directly to the MX. Submit your message to a local mail server and let it relay to the MX for you. If you send using PHPMailer with SMTP you will get much better feedback on deliveries. As for what cPanel is doing, check the local mail server log, usually in `/var/log/mail.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the setting from local to "Remote Mail Exchanger" in dns zone file. and also create mail account at remote location site.